# Counting non duplicated values from a column using other column with dates as criteria

Tags: excel

I'm going right to the problem;

I have a table (table 1) with a field named "Nº"; other named "Data da consulta".

In table1[Nº] i have the number of a patient, like if i was a patient i would get number 1, the next patient number 2, and when i come again to hospital i'm still the number 1.
In table1[Data da consulta], i have the date of visiting the hospital

Now, i want to count, the non duplicated numbers of table1[Nº]; with a criteria between dates using table1[data da consulta]. with that i get the number of patients seen between dates. For example number of patients between 01-01-2018 and 31-03-2018, and if patient number 1 come 2 or more times between this dates only count as 1 patients.

Did you get??

I try this, but is not working

=SUM(IF(Table1[Data da Consulta]>=$B$1;IF(Table1[Data da Consulta]<=$C$1;IF(FREQUENCY(Table1[Nº];Table1[Nº])>0;1;0))))

B1 is the 1st date of interval and C1 the last date of interval of dates.

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1133T.jpg)

Comment: Could you please post some data as example? It would help to make this question clear.

Comment: i posted an image right now

Comment: @pnuts I can't do that cause this must be in a worksheet with more information, like a summary of a "data base" in excel

Answer (score 0):

This formula, entered as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>, should give you the result you want.  Adjust the ranges to match your actual data. In my test `D1` was the minimum date and `D2` was the maximum date.

```
=SUM(IFERROR((A3:A23<>"")*(B3:B23>=D1)*(B3:B23<=D2)/COUNTIFS(A3:A23,A3:A23,B3:B23,">="&D1,B3:B23,"<="&D2),0))
```

EDIT:

For Excel where you need semi-colon delimited arguments for your functions:

```
=SUM(IFERROR((A3:A23<>"")*(B3:B23>=D1)*(B3:B23<=D2)/COUNTIFS(A3:A23;A3:A23;B3:B23;">="&D1;B3:B23;"<="&D2);0))
```

Comment: COUNTIFS(A3:A23,A3:A23) this part is deliver me an error, and i use excel 2007, i switch "," to ";"

Comment: @Tiago I have included a version of the formula that uses semi-colons `;` to delimit the arguments instead of commas `,`

Comment: COUNTIFS(A3:A23,A3:A23) this give me an error, criterea range1 and criterea 1 is the same??

Comment: @Tiago Yes, the criteria range1 and criteria1 are the same in that  formula.  I noticed you posted the version using the comma again.  Try using the semicolon version of the formula.

Comment: Sry @tigeravatar, when i push Ctrl + Shift + Enter, i still recived a error message and then COUNTIFS(A3:A23;A3:A23) was selected :/